# Limit of daily liquids - higher with electrolyte supplement?

Tags: water, water-retention, sodium, electrolytes, diluting

I have been advised to consistently drink 100 (one hundred) oz of water/water-based liquids every day. I've done pretty well at keeping to that, but now that I have a cold, I'd like to drink more. On the other hand, I understand that the first undesirable thing too much liquids will result in is over-diluting the electrolytes in my blood. I know that there are electrolyte supplements, such as Gatorade, and even calorie-free supplements that are easy to fit into my diet. 
How much is known about how much electrolytes I should add for how much water I drink beyond some point, and at what point does it start approaching overhydration?

Comment: So in a nutshell, what are you trying to ask

Comment: What would be a good protocol for washing out the germs from my body with lots of water without overdoing it, doing things to raise the limit?

Comment: You cannot wash germs out of your body.

Comment: I know I can't wash live gems, but I also know it helps to drink lots of liquids. I think it reduces the time the white blood cells need to spend holding on to the dead bodies of the germs they've killed, or something like that.